# Problem with Flask-mysql fetchall in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I need some help. I can't fetchall results from mysql through python. I've got this error: This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 unexpectedly closed the connection.
ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Here is my code:

```js
...
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
...
app = Flask(__name__)
mysql=MySQL(app)
# config mysql
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = '****'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = '****'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '****'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = '****'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = ****
# Init
mysql.init_app(app)

...

@app.route('/myapps')
@is_logged_in
def myapps():
    cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()
    username = session['username']
    result = cur.execute("select * from appointments where username= %s",[username])
    if result > 0:
        myapps = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('myapps.html', myapps = myapps)
    else:
        msg = 'No appointments found'
        return render_template('myapps.html', msg=msg)
    cur.close()
```

```html
<tbody>
            {% for app in myapps %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{app.app_id}}</th>
            <td>{{app.services}}</td>
            <td>{{app.start_date}}</td>
            <td>{{app.end_date}}</td>
            <td>{{app.start_hour}}</td>
            <td>{{app.end_hour}}</td>
            <td>{{app.creation_date}}</td>
            <td>{{app.username}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you share more info about the error log? seems your db connection setting is not correct, have you ever tried some other method to connect your db in order to make sure your setting is valid?

Comment: You do not have to pass the `app` object to `MySQL` constructor. Simply do `mysql=MySQL()`

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql.get_db().cursor(buffered=True)
```

Try setting the buffered parameter to True inside cursor.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys but I solved the problem by using

import pymysql